# sifr jquery slide conflict show

Tags: jquery-plugins, sifr, sifr3

I'm using jquery cycle plugin by malsup for a slide show that includes text. I want sifr to replace the text. It does so on the first slide, but not the subsequent ones. Any idea what might be done so that sifr is applied to the text on each slide as it is displayed?

Here's my sample page (I've made the sfir text blue and green so I know immediately it it works--it does work in FF 3.6, but not Safari 5.0.3 or Chrome 8 on my Mac...
http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/testimonials/index-07.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay--so I just added in a second call sIFR.replace code--this time with a very brief delay so that the nest paragraph loads and then sIFR.replace is called. Here's the jquery code:

$('#next').click(

```
     function() {

             to = setTimeout(function ()    
              {sIFR.replace(helvetica, 
              {selector: 'p', 
              css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #e6e6e6; color: #0000FF; font-size: 13px; text-align: justify; text-indent: 30px;   }'}); }, 
              100); // call sIFR code after this many milliseconds
              }); });
```